# Is it possible to know how many Oracle connections are opened in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, database-connection, adodb

I have an excel macro. Macro is connecting to Oracle to fetch data. 
This fetching may or may not open more than one connections (depending how users have coded inside macro).

Is it possible to know Oracle connections opened in excel vba ? or
I rephrase my question: Is it possible to know how many connections were opened from that Excel macro in VBA script ?

Connection Code:

```
Public Const CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=XXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Data Source=XXXXX;Persist Security Info=True"   
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
conn.Open CONNECT_STRING
MsgBox Application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count
```

> Count is still 0

Comment: "how many connections were opened from that excel macro in VBA script " - why does that matter?

Comment: is it in the ActiveWorkbook.Connections object?

Comment: It depends on many factors, such as: how do you connect to Oracle database? We need to see your code...

Comment: Mitch: It's one of requirement. @JoelSpolsky: I tried ActiveWorkbook.Connections.count.. but still zero.

Comment: Added my code for reference.

Comment: That's not what `ActiveWorkbook.Connections` is for. That would show the number of pivot tables, query tables, etc. that are using a connection; VBA connections are totally independent of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no... and yes.

There is nothing built in to keep track of how many ADODB connections you have open to a particular database. You would have to keep track of this yourself if it is a requirement.

You could do this by adding each of your connections to a collection as you create them and then write a function to check two things before returning a count.

1. Make sure the connection object isn't `Nothing`
2. Make sure the connection is open before counting it by checking the [connection's state property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675068(v=vs.85).aspx).

   ```
   Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
   For Each conn in someCollection
       If Not conn Is Nothing Then
           If conn.State <> adStateClosed Then
               count = count + 1
           End If
       End If
   Next conn
   ```

You're on your own to figure out how you want to actually track all of the connections in your project.